# R read matrix of integer values automatically

Tags: r, matrix, import

I want to read a matrix (all values, no null or empty column) from a tab-separated **text file** of integers and name the columns automatically (based on the titles in the first line):

```
a   b   c
9   2   3
2   9   6
3   2   4
5   3   3
```

I have tried read.csv(), read.table() and scan() methods and read the file, but I want something that:

> 1- Automatically identifies the column names (no need to mention the
> names one by one).
>
> 2- I would be able to treat them as matrix of integers; run **rcorr(data)** and **quantile(data$a, 0.9)** instead of **rcorr(as.matrix(data))** and **quantile(as.matrix(data$a), 0.9)** any time.

Any ideas on the simplest (yet efficient) way?

Comment: I'm sort of at a loss as to what the big problem is with using `read.table` and then just coercing it to a matrix...?

Comment: `txt <- "a\tb\tc\n9\t2\t3\n2\t9\t6\n3\t2\t4\n5\t3\t3"` is your data (see `cat(txt)` ) - `as.matrix(read.table(text=txt,sep="\t",header=TRUE))` will work fine and give you exactly what you want.

Comment: @thelatemail: you are right. Thank you. I just figured out the problem which was a special character (#) in the header titles.

Comment: @joran, Thanx. See the other comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
data <-- as.matrix(read.table("c:\\temp\\inFile.tsv", header=TRUE))
```

Note that I got the following error when there was special characters (#) in the header line:

> Error in read.table("..."), : more columns than column names

So there shouldn't be special characters in the header line. Also it automatically detects the separator ("\t").

Answer (score 1):

How about `read.table`?

```
read.table(text="a b c
                 9 2 3
                 2 9 6
                 3 2 4
                 5 3 3", header=TRUE)

>      a b c
     1 9 2 3
     2 2 9 6
     3 3 2 4
     4 5 3 3
```

it also has options to input file, declare the separator, etc.. see `help(read.table)`

Comment: I am reading from a file.     Anyway, data <-- read.table("c:\\temp\\inFile.tsv", header=TRUE) generates "more columns than column names" error.

Comment: @Alisa You could try it with `row.names = 1` or some other value depending on what your actual data looks like

Comment: @Alisa Then you just haven't specified all the arguments right. You might try `sep = "\t"`.

Comment: @Alisa Do you have data in your csv file different than what you posted?

Comment: @N8TRO: Yes, there was a special character in the header which I thought is not important! Thank you.